# How to transfer a file to the converter function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way to transfer a file to a function that converts different formats to pdf.  The transfer takes place at the moment of saving the source file to AWS S3 inside the `perform_create()` function. When I pass a file stored on the local machine to the function manually everything works.

```
class DocumentsListView(AwsUrlMixin, viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    .....
    .....
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        file = serializer.validated_data['filedata']
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)
        random_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
        file.name = f'{random_name}{ext}'
        url = self._get_aws_url(file)#get the link to private S3 directory for file download or view
        if ext != 'pdf':
            directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
            convert_to_pdf(file, directory)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, url_link=url)
```

**models.py**

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    ....
    filedata = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    url_link = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

**convert_function.py**

```
from subprocess import  Popen
LIBRE_OFFICE = '/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice'

def convert_to_pdf(input_docx, out_folder):
    p = Popen([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir',
               out_folder, input_docx])
    print([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--convert-to', 'pdf', input_docx])
    p.communicate()
```

I got an error

```
  File "/home/y700/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1447, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
```

I've also tried this way (using **url** instead of **file** instances as an argument for the function `convert_to_pdf`)

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    file = serializer.validated_data['filedata']
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)
    random_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    file.name = f'{random_name}{ext}'
    url = self._get_aws_url(file)
    if ext != 'pdf':
        directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        convert_to_pdf(url, directory)
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user, url_link=url)
```

But got an error

```
Error: source file could not be loaded
```

Comment: Your converter needs a path to a local file, not a `File` object. In the first case you're passing a `File`, in the second case you're passing the path on S3 where the file will be saved but isn't saved yet (and `Popen` isn't using the S3 boto3 storage backend so it doesn't know how to open such a file anyway). Save the file locally in a temp directory (and delete if afterwards) before passing it to your converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your converter needs a path to a local file, not a `File` object. In the first case you're passing a `File`, in the second case you're passing the path on S3 where the file will be saved but isn't saved yet (and `Popen` isn't using the S3 boto3 storage backend so it doesn't know how to open such a file anyway).

Save the file locally in a temp directory (and delete if afterwards) before passing it to your converter.